# Determine whether the integral is positive or negative.

Tags: definite-integrals

[image: the integral itself which should be evaluated]

I can't think of any proper way to show that this integral is indeed positive (I got that it's positive from Wolfram Alpha). Please, help me!

Answer (score 3):

You can split your integral in two parts:
$$ I = \int_{-2}^2x^{2017}\,2016^x\,dx = \int_{-2}^0x^{2017}\,2016^x\,dx + \int_{0}^2x^{2017}\,2016^x\,dx.$$

Swapping the bounds of the  first integral and applying the change of variables $y = -x$,
$$\int_{-2}^0x^{2017}\,2016^x\,dx = -\int_0^{-2} x^{2017}\,2016^x\,dx = \int_{0}^2 -y^{2017} \,2016^{-y} \,dy.$$
Renaming the dummy variable $y$ as $x$ and going back to the first equation:
$$ I = \int_{0}^2x^{2017}\,(2016^x - 2016^{-x})\,dx.$$
The expression between round brackets is greater than  $0$ on $(0,2]$, so $I$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain why we can 'Renaming the dummy variable y as x'? How can we just rename?

Answer (score 2):

The net contribution of $x^{2017}$ will be zero, as it is an odd function. However, the other component, ${2016}^x$ is strictly positive but much higher on the $x>0$ side than the other one. Therefore, the 'weight' of $x^{2017}$ on that side (its positive side) is increased, and the integral is positive.